# hornetq Consumer Flow Control

Tags: jms, hornetq

I read at http://hornetq.sourceforge.net/docs/hornetq-2.0.0.GA/user-manual/en/html/flow-control.html

"Consumer Flow Control

This controls the flow of data between the server and the client as the client consumes messages. For performance reasons clients normally buffer messages before delivering to the consumer via the receive() method or asynchronously via a message listener. If the consumer cannot process messages as fast as they are being delivered and stored in the internal buffer, then you could end up with a situation where messages would keep building up possibly causing out of memory on the client if they cannot be processed in time."

but I don't understand ...
what is the meaning of clients ? does it means different jvm than the server jvm ? so hornetq server will deliver messages from the queue (or topic ?) to the client jvm heap in order the receiver to consume them from in memory ? what if the client is in same jvm as server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client can be in a different JVM or the same JVM in case of MDB deployed on the same server as the HornetQ broker. The only difference will be the type of connect it will use. In case of different JVM it will use netty connector and and in case of the same JVM it will use inVM connector. In both cases flow control will behave exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks , but still I don't understand. The client is my own standalone application (that implement a jms reciver ). so how does my client buffer messages ?? what is the mechanism and how this is possible on my own code ??

Comment: Yes, but unless you have completely reimplemnted the HornetQ client, you will be using hornetq jars to connect to the message broker. So when you create connection and then session it initialise the client runtime side where messages are buffered.